# Is there any app for android mobile to connect to roscore directly?

Tags: ros, android-teleop, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've to control robot simulator using android mobile.
Will someone tell me is there any app available to connect my android to the laptop in which I've installed ROS (robot operating system) in order to run the robot using android mobile.
I've to move the robot (right left up and down) using the android mobile.
Please Help.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45606/is-there-any-app-for-android-mobile-to-connect-to-roscore-directly?/) by [kush6791](https://answers.ros.org/users/3349/kush6791/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot/Tutorials/AndroidControl). When running simulation and using your PC as ros master in the android application, you should be able to teleop for instance a turtlebot in gazebo.

Btw. please tag your questions to make sure that people who can help actually find it.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kush6791](https://answers.ros.org/users/3349/kush6791/) on 2012-10-11**:
I'am supposed to move turtlesim using android mobile.
Kindly tell me the steps to connect android mobile to roscore to move turtlesim using mobile.
I've installed ROS_android_sensor_driver in mobile and try to connect it with roscore but didn't worked for me.
There is no reaction.Thanks in advance.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-12**:
You will probably not find an application that can do exactly that, i.e. you will have to implement something yourself. I doubt that someone here on this site will give you a complete solution, in particular as long as your questions are that high-level and vague. See http://ros.org/wiki/Support